# Source for Oracle's MySQL installer for Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, open-source

Does anyone know if I can download the source for the installer used for the binary distribution for MySQL on OS X? I don't mean the MySQL source, I know that's easy to find, but rather the Installer scripts (including postflight, etc) that are contained with the DMG you can download from the MySQL website. I'd like to try and drop MariaDB in the installer instead of build my own installer from scratch. There are also problems with the Startup items that need repairing. I'm having a difficult time stringing together the right phrase in Google to find this, nor did I find it on MySQL.com (vanilla source code tar.gz does not contain any OS X items).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a member of the MariaDB team and they showed me that it's in an old version of the MySQL bzr repository:

```
bzr branch -r date:2005-04-22 lp:mysql-server mysql-server-2005-04-22
```

The script to generate the installer is at Build-tools/Do-pkg

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the OSX installer comes from an internal source code repository. It was never open-sourced.